# What does the following fields: 'totalSize' and 'rawDataSize' mean in DESCRIBE EXTENDED query output in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

If one runs DESCRIBE EXTENDED command on any hive table the result presents totalSize and rawDataSize values near the end of the output.

What do these fields mean?

Ex:

```
hive > DESCRIBE EXTENDED <TableName>

Output Results:

Table(tableName:TablenameXXXXX, dbName:XXxXXX,
..........       .......................
numRows=116429472, totalSize=3835205544, rawDataSize=35040221600})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

rawDataSize is the size of original data set, totalSize is amount of storage it takes. It is applicable for ORC file format, as it compresses the data totalSize will be lesser than rawDataSize.

Comment: Does the totalSize reflect used space in terms of the used data portion only, or does it included used data portion and any unused portion of an HDFS block?

Comment: Is the totalSize a multiple of the HDFS block size?

Comment: It need not be multiple of block size. HDFS does not waste storage on the last block of the file. If the file size is 200 MB and block size is 128 MB, then first block will be of size 128 MB and second block will be of 72 MB

Comment: @Neal : the totalSize is in Bytes according to this [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev)

Comment: in case of `Parquet` format, the `rawDataSize` is still smaller than `totalSize`, but how is it possible? Parquet format should compress the original data. I'm totally confused

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju what it the unit of rawDataSize here bit/byte?

Answer (score 7):

The meaning of the fields is:

- totalSize - the total size in bytes of the physical files on disk where table data is stored.
- rawDataSize - is the sum of each datatype size of the
  columns multiplied by the number of rows in the table. This is also
  used as an estimate for the query optimizer (e.g. determining if a
  table is small enough to do a mapjoin instead of simple join).

Answer (score 2):

The size of data is described by two statistics:

- totalSize — Approximate size of data on disk
- rawDataSize — Approximate size of data in memory

Hive on MapReduce uses totalSize. When both are available, Hive on Spark uses rawDataSize. Because of compression and serialization, a large difference between totalSize and rawDataSize can occur for the same dataset.